# Django TemplateView Context Not Rendering on Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I know this has probably been asked a million times, but I searched forever and couldn't find an answer. I'm trying to create several select drop downs to use as a search filter on my index page. I have loaded the models with data, but when I try to render the data on the template, I'm not seeing what is in the model. Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import LengthRange, Hull


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['length_ranges'] = LengthRange.objects.all()
        context['hull_types'] = Hull.objects.all()
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
]
```

and my snippet from **index.html**:

```
    <h2 class="about-item__text">
A boat with a length of
       <select>
           <option value="*" selected>any size</option>
            {% for length in length_ranges %}
                                        <option value="{{ length.pk }}">{{ length.range }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
                                , with hull type of
                                <select>
                                    <option value="*" selected>any</option>
                                    {% for hull in hull_types %}
                                        <option value="{{ hull.pk }}">{{ hull.type }}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </select>
```

It's been a really long time since I worked in Django, but this should have been relatively easy. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `TemplateView` in your URL pattern - you should import your view and use that instead.

```
from myapp.views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Comment: That fixed it. Guess I should have mentioned that this was my first time trying to use class based views as well. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it's the first time you've used class-based-views or not, the key thing is you posted enough code to show what the problem was ;)